# Excel file generation using SQL query, SPOOL command in Shell script

Tags: excel, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have to generate excel file from tables from `Oracle Database`. The code is working fine but however the column names are not coming completely, there are just coming as the length of there data length.
I want complete header/column names

The column names are coming like this

```
ST  STAT_TYPE_DESC   ST  S  NXT_STATME  DELAY_DAYS  ANN_PREM_LIM_LOW ANN_PREM_LIM_HI    CONTRIB_HIST_LEN    EVENT_DO    C   P
```

But I want is complete names of the columns, for example `ST` is **STATEMENT_TYPE_ID**

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE="A.csv"

sqlplus -s lifelite/lifelite@dv10  <<EOF

SPOOL $FILE
SET HEADING ON
SET HEADSEP OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF  
SET LINESIZE 250
SET PAGESIZE 5000 embedded ON
SET COLSEP ","

SELECT * FROM TLLI_01150STATTYPE;
EOF
SPOOL OFF
EXIT 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your select add a new one with the column names:

```
SELECT 'STATEMENT_TYPE_ID' || ',' || 'STAT_TYPE_DESC' || ',' || ... FROM dual;
```

And set heading off

Comment: Thankyou btpys, this is a good idea when tables to be extracted is less. What if I have extract 160 tables, then manually I can't write column names and select * from dual.

Comment: Then you can query dba_tab_columns to make the selects